# I am unable to edit HTML files in VS Code. The cursor does not appear for HTML files, but other file types are editable. What might be the cause?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[No editor is visible for the HTML file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U05kp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the HTML file from and select "Open with" and then "Configure default editor for for '*.html'" and then select "Text Editor" all HTML files should open up in the Text Editor